How do i recover the bit coin i purchased via online with a credit card 20 years ago?
I was just 18 years old,  living at my parents. Always playing on computers.  We had AOL at the time.  I still remember my password. I remember my email address.  But my parents passed away and the aol account was in there name.  My parent have been gone for over 10 years now and lost that screen name when the account got closed because ofnthe death of my parents.   Who could i reach out to forbhelp on a recovery option?

Bitcoin didn’t exist 20 years ago. Anyway, to recover it, you need the wallet’s private keys. Emails or accounts may help if they hold recovery info, but without private keys, access to ₿ is impossible. For your parents’ email, contact AOL directly.
